# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized while downloading Zip file from network

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any other way I can download the same(i.e wget/svn)

```
import urllib.request
import zipfile
import ssl

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context



urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://svne1.access.nokiasiemensnetworks.com/isource/svnroot/oss_cpf/components/art_cpfwas855/java8_fixes/fixpack8_0_5_17/8.0.5.17-WS-IBMWASJAVA-Linux.zip","fixpack8_0_5_17")

with zipfile.ZipFile('fixpack8_0_5_17',"r") as z :
    z.extractall("downloads//")

print("Download Complete")
```

Comment: Please include your full error message as well please. Also: Are you asking why your code is not working or for another way to download data from a URL?

Comment: my code is not working ..